# How to get child element by index in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="second">
    <div class="selector" id="selFirst"></div>
    <div class="selector" id="selSecond"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

How to get #selFirst using element index not the ID?

this:

```
var $selFirst = $(".second:nth-child(1)");
console.log($selFirst);
```

is returning :

```
jQuery(div.second)
```

Answer (score 211, accepted):

If you know the child element you're interested in is the first:

```
 $('.second').children().first();
```

Or to find by index:

```
 var index = 0
 $('.second').children().eq(index);
```

Comment: Look out: eq() is 0-indexed, but index() is 1-indexed.

Comment: The question is more general. How to select by index. It's not about how to select first child.

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov note the second example, which uses the index

Answer (score 22):

There are the following way to select first child

```
1) $('.second div:first-child')
```

```
2) $('.second *:first-child')
```

```
3) $('div:first-child', '.second')
```

```
4) $('*:first-child', '.second')
```

```
5) $('.second div:nth-child(1)')
```

```
6) $('.second').children().first()
```

```
7) $('.second').children().eq(0)
```

Comment: the more choices you provide, the more upvotes you get!

Comment: The question is more general. How to select by index. It's not about how to select first child.

Answer (score 7):

You can get first element via index selector:

```
$('div.second div:eq(0)')
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/RX46D/

Comment: index selectors are bad. Use methods instead, they are faster

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.second').find('div:first')
```

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't nth-child return siblings rather than children?

```
var $selFirst = $(".second:nth-child(1)");
```

will return the first element with the class '.second'.

```
var $selFirst = $(".selector:nth-child(1)");
```

should give you the first sibling of class '.selector'

Answer (score -6):

`var node = document.getElementsByClassName("second")[0].firstElementChild`

**Disclaimer:** Browser compliance on `getElementsByClassName` and `firstElementChild` are shaky. DOM-shims fix those problems though.

Comment: Bear in mind that if the OP is looking for the first DIV, this will not work if there any HTML elements between .second and #selFirst.

Comment: Where did he say "first DIV". Where did he say "there will be elements between .second and #selFirst"